# If $\gcd(a,35)=1$ then show that $a^{12} \equiv 1  \pmod{35}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $\gcd(a,35)=1$, then show that $a^{12}\equiv1\pmod{35}$

I have tried this problem beginning with $a^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$ and $a^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ (Fermat's Theorem) but couldn't get far enough. Please help.

Comment: Good start... So, $a^{12}=$____$\pmod{7}$ and $a^{12}=$____$\pmod{5}$. Can you fill in?

Comment: @did oh yes !!! 1,1 and I got it .Thanks for the hint.How could I miss that :(

Comment: You are welcome. Surely you know that you may write your own solution, post it here as an answer, wait a little bit, and accept it. It is even recommanded...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since $\gcd(a,7) =\gcd(a,5) = 1$, from Fermat's theorem,
$$a^6\equiv 1\pmod7 \quad \text{ and } \quad a^4\equiv1\pmod5.
$$
Hence,
$$ a^{12}\equiv 1\pmod7 \quad \text{ and } \quad a^{12}\equiv1\pmod5.
$$
This means that
$$7\mid a^{12}-1 \quad\text{ and } \quad 5\mid a^{12}-1.
$$
Since $\gcd(7,5)=1$,
$$35\mid a^{12}-1,
$$
that is,
$$
a^{12}\equiv1\pmod{35}.
$$

Comment: How do you go from a^6 ≡1 => a^12 ≡ 1 ?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to use [Euler's totient theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem). You are familiar with Fermat's little theorem, and this is a generalized version. This approach is lengthier, but instructive, because it shows that the totient function doesn't always give you the minimal exponent. For more information, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

From the theorem, we know

$$a^{\phi(35)} \equiv_{35} 1$$

A simple computation shows that $\phi(35)=24$ (this can be shortened if you know more about the $\phi$ function).

So we have

$$a^{24}\equiv 1. $$

In general, if $k^2\equiv 1$, we see $(k-1)(k+1)\equiv 0$, so $k\equiv 1$ or $k\equiv -1$ (You need to think for a moment to see that other cases are ruled out, as this isn't an integral domain). Applying this to the above, we will be done once we rule out the case

$$a^{12}\equiv -1.$$

In particular, we would need $(a^6)^2$ to be $-1$ mod $35$. To show $-1$ is not a square mod $35$, it suffices to show it is not a square mod $7$ (if $a^2$ was -1 mod 35, the same $a$ mod 7 would produce $a^2\equiv -1$ mod 7).

And it is easy to see by checking all possibilities that $-1$ is not the square of any number when considered modulo 7.

Comment: Interesting solution by residues, instead of the further extension of the original approach. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Potato In the $3\text{rd}$ paragraph how you had written "In general, if $k^2 \equiv 1$ we see....." 
How other cases are ruled out e.g. $k^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ then $k \equiv 1 \text{ or } k\equiv -1 \text{ or } k\equiv 4....$

Comment: We have the factorization $(k-1)(k+1)\equiv_{35} 0$. The numbers on the left have to be 0 or divisors of $35$. I actually forgot to explicitly write out the case $k=6$, but that's not hard to see using the same methods I used. But $k\equiv 4$ won't work, for example, because $3*15=15$, which is not a multiple of $35$.

Comment: @Potato:If $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n) =1$ and  $a \equiv c (\text{mod m})$, $b \equiv d (\text{mod n})$, then $ab \equiv cd (\text{mod mn})$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that:

- If $a \equiv b \ (\text{mod m})$ then $a^{2} \equiv b^{2} \ (\text{mod m})$.
- If $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n) =1$ and  $a \equiv 1 (\text{mod m})$, $b \equiv 1 (\text{mod n})$, then $ab \equiv 1 (\text{mod mn})$.

Comment: One would also need the hint that $a^3=b^3\pmod{m}$.

Comment: @Saurabh: It is a Complete hint.

Comment: @did: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @user9413:If $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n) =1$ and  $a \equiv c (\text{mod m})$, $b \equiv d (\text{mod n})$, then $ab \equiv cd (\text{mod mn})$???